# I need a final tweak to this CASE statement

Tags: sql, case

I have the following piece of code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (ACCT.NMAJORHCODE IN ('7','16') 
AND DET_TYPE NOT IN ('ACR', 'ADR', 'CRN'))
OR (DET_TYPE IN ('ADR', 'CRN') AND CR.NMAJORHCODE < 4 AND ACCT.NTYPE NOT IN ('A', 'X'))
THEN -NL.DET_FINAL
ELSE NL.DET_FINAL
```

This will loop through fifteen databases.  However, one of the database operates to slightly different business rules and, in the above example, the final two lines need to be

```
THEN NL.DET_FINAL
ELSE -NL.DET_FINAL
```

i.e the signs are reversed.

How can I get my CASE statement to behave how I want?  In English, when I get to the THEN clause it would be "make the number negative unless DB_NAME() = 'Proteus' in which case make it positive".

Similarly, the ELSE needs sign reversing.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move it out into a separate expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (ACCT.NMAJORHCODE IN ('7','16') 
AND DET_TYPE NOT IN ('ACR', 'ADR', 'CRN'))
OR (DET_TYPE IN ('ADR', 'CRN') AND CR.NMAJORHCODE < 4 AND ACCT.NTYPE NOT IN ('A', 'X'))
THEN -NL.DET_FINAL
ELSE NL.DET_FINAL END * CASE WHEN DB_NAME() = 'PROTEUS' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```

(And, a note on terminology - `CASE` is an *expression* (it computes a value), not a *statement*)

Comment: Thank you both, you guys make these things seem so easy :-(

Answer (score 1):

You could nest `case`, like:

```
THEN CASE DB_NAME() WHEN 'PROTEUS' THEN -NL.DET_FINAL ELSE NL.DET_FINAL END
ELSE CASE DB_NAME() WHEN 'PROTEUS' THEN NL.DET_FINAL ELSE -NL.DET_FINAL END
END
```